# I want to sort a list in a method with respect to the method's argument

Tags: python, list, sorting, key

I have a method and as an argument I enter x and y coordinates of a point and then I calculate the power reached to that [x,y] coordinate from other points and sort them in order of highest power reached to lowest:

```
def power_at_each_point(x_cord, y_cord):
    nodez_list = [nodes_in_room for nodes_in_room in range(1, len(Node_Positions_Ascending) + 1)]
    powers_list = []
    for each_node in nodez_list:
    powers_list.append(cal_pow_rec_plandwall(each_node, [x_cord, y_cord]))
    return max(powers_list)
```

I want to do that in a more pythonic way like `key = cal_pow_rec_plandwall` but this method takes two arguments and not one.
So how can I do it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need a single call to `max` which takes a generator as an argument. The `lambda` expression is just to make things more readable.

```
def power_at_each_point(x_cord, y_coord):
    f = lambda x: cal_pow_rec_plandwall(x, [x_coord, y_coord])      
    return max(f(each_node) for each_node in xrange(1, len(Node_Positions_Ascending) + 1))
```

You can replace the generator with a call to `itertools.imap`:

```
from itertools import imap

def power_at_each_point(x_coord, y_coord):
    f = lambda x: cal_pow_rec_plandwall(x, [x_coord, y_coord])
    return max(imap(f, xrange(1, len(Node_Positions_Ascending) + 1)))
```

Comment: At no point do you actually need all the values; `max` just needs to look at them one at a time and keep the largest it has seen to date. In Python 2, this saves building the entire list up front; in Python 3, the built-in `map` will work fine.

Comment: (For the same reason I just changed `range` to `xrange` for use in Python 2.)